# length vs length_m in osm_ways table

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Postgresql, postgis (in table: berlin_ways), where this table is generated from importing berlin osm.

what is the difference between length and length_m, and what is the unit distance for each of them?

[image: berlin_ways]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`length` is in degrees and doesn't mean much.

`length_m` is in meters.

Using the 1st set of coordinates from your sample table:

```sql
--(CRS unit, 4326, degrees)
select st_distance(st_makePoint(113.8543481,22.8171585),st_makePoint(113.8545562,22.8187095));
     st_distance 
---------------------
 0.00156489827464957
(1 row)


-- (cast to Geography, so meters)
select st_distance(st_makePoint(113.8543481,22.8171585)::geography,st_makePoint(113.8545562,22.8187095)::geography);
 st_distance
--------------
 173.08351329
(1 row)
```